# Does the simplicial-set internal hom of quasicategories give a quasicategory?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, simplicial-stuff

The internal hom structure on simplicial sets is described [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SimpSet#cartesian_closed_monoidal_structure). This provides us with a functor $h : C^{\text{op}} \times C \rightarrow C$ where $C := \mathrm{Sets}^{\mathbf{\Delta}^{\text{op}}}$.

My question is, if some given $X,Y \in \mathrm{Obj}(C)$ are in fact [quasicategories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quasi-category#definition), then is $h(X,Y) \in \mathrm{Obj}(C)$ also a quasicategory? Would anyone know of a reference that discusses this?

---

Update: I have found a discussion of this in Lurie's Higher Topos Theory, Proposition 1.2.7.3, and the Proposition following 2.2.5.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: see Lurie, Higher Topos Theory, Proposition 1.2.7.3.

Also see the Proposition following 2.2.5.7; it is a proof of 1.2.7.3.